# Continuity of functions in a metric space.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $\mathbb N^{\mathbb N}$ be the set of sequences of natural numbers ($0 \notin \mathbb N$) and let for sequences $a=(n_1,n_2,\ldots)$, $b=(m_1,m_2,...)$ be:

$$d(a,b)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{\min(i: n_i\neq m_i)},  & \text{if $a \neq b$} \\
0, & \text{if $a=b$}  \\
\end{cases}
$$

Let $f,g \colon \mathbb N^{\mathbb N} \to \mathbb R$ be described as below:
$$f(n_1,n_2,...)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty 2^{-i}\frac{1}{n_i} $$
$$g(n_1,n_2,...)=\sup \left\{ \frac{n_i}{1+n_i}:i=1,2,\ldots \right\}$$

Are the functions $f$, $g$ continuous if we consider $\mathbb N^{\mathbb N}$ with topology induced by metric $d$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. Consider $|f(a)-f(b)|$. If $d(a, b) = \frac 1 k$, how large can $|f(a)-f(b)|$ get?

**Hint**. Consider that $g$ doesn't care about the ordering of the sequence and $d$ does. Use this to build a counter example.

Comment: As regarding $f$ I got that if $d(a,b)=\frac{1}{k}$ then $|f(a)-f(b)| \lt \sum_{i=k}^\infty \frac{1}{2^i}$ and this is less than $\frac{1}{k}$ so $f$ is a contraction, so it satisfies the Lipschitz conditio and hence it is uniformly continuous so it must be continuous as well. Is it right?

Comment: @user114119, yes.